# Javascript apply - кастомная реализация

Tags: javascript

Есть абстрактная функция, которая на вход принимает параметр и потом что то делает с этим параметром. Хочу реализовать функцию так, чтобы на вход можно было передавать сколько угодно параметров в виде массива.
Прочитал, что метод apply позволяет делать такое и так понял что мой кастомный метод должен уметь работать с параметром как с числом так и с массивом - без этого apply делает просто вызов функции

не понимаю как реализовать функцию apply для своего метода

```
function add(){ 
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        arr.push(arguments[i]);
}

  return arr;
}

var x = add(1);

var y = add.apply(null, [1,2,3]);
var z = add(1,2,3);
```

Получается что add(1,2,3) и add.apply(null, [1,2,3]) возвращают одно и тоже. В чем тогда разница вызова этих функций, не считая контекста вызова , который можно передавать в apply

Есть такая функция Math.min(). Она умеет принимать n-количество параметров, но и с помощью apply может принимать массив параметров. Без apply функция не умеет работать с массивом

Это я неправильно реализовываю функцию или как ?

Comment: Между add(1,2,3) и add.apply(null, [1,2,3]) нет совершенно никакой разницы.

Comment: `apply` как раз и отличается только контекстом вызова + сама ф-я по определению принимает вторым аргументом массив

Comment: add([1,2,3]) да но так она мне тоже возвращает массив с масивом.
Math.min([1,2,3]) же возвращает NaN. я так думаю что это правильнее или нет?

Comment: @ruslik, поведение Math.min описано в [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.min): _If any value is NaN, the result is NaN_, и `isNaN([1,2,3]) === true`

Comment: @ddeadlink, уже не массив, а _array-like_

Comment: то есть мне нужно написать проверку на входной параметр. Почему изначально функция Math.min не способна принимать массив. Для чего то они сделали же это

Comment: @ruslik, функция Math.min - вообще не способна принимать массив. вызов `apply` просто позволяет вызвать функцию, которая может принимать переменное число параметров, когда ты не знаешь сколько именно параметров у тебя будет для передачи.

Comment: _на вход можно было передавать сколько угодно параметров в виде массива_ - судя по твоей задаче, ты ее не правильно реализовал. В твоей функции должен был быть _один_ параметр - массив. А в данный момент ты работаешь со списком аргументов.

Comment: Если передавать массив в качестве параметра, то какой тогда толк от apply. Нужно поведение именно как Math.min

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56935/discussion-between-grundy-and-ruslik).

Comment: Считай, что apply - просто удобный метод вызова функции с множеством аргументов при наличии массива. Вместо `foo(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], ...)`

Comment: @vp_arth, либо foo(...arr) =)